# Evaluation of $\langle nlm|\frac{1}{r^2}|nlm\rangle$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, hydrogen, orbitals

I am trying to prove that $$⟨nlm|\frac{1}{^2}|nlm⟩=\frac{1}{^3*^2*(l+\frac{1}{2})}$$
(where $$ is the Bohr radius) for the $|⟩$ state of hydrogen. I know how to do this using [Hellmann–Feynman theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellmann%E2%80%93Feynman_theorem) , and I am trying to use the conventional way of evaluating $\int_{0}^{\infty} \Psi_{nlm}^*\frac{1}{^2}\Psi_{nlm} \,dr $ to derive the result. However, I got stuck at  $\int_{0}^{\infty} R_{nl}^*(r)R_{nl}(r) \,dr $. I tried to write out $R_{nl}^*(r)$ and $R_{nl}(r)$ but got stuck at
$$
\Bigl( \frac{2}{na} \Bigr)^3 \frac{(n-l-1)!}{2n(n+l)!} \int_{0}^{\infty}e^\frac{-2r}{na} \Bigl( \frac{2r}{na} \Bigr)^{2l} \bigl( L_{n-l-1}^{2l+1}(2r/na) \bigr)^2 \, dr
$$
Could anyone help me point out what to do next? Thank you very much!

Comment: Firstly, I strongly suggest you use a new radial variable to simplify things: $u = 2 r / n a$.  Secondly, you should have $u^{2 l}$ inside your integral, not just $u^l$ (since the wave function is squared). Unless it is inside the parenthesis...

Comment: already fixed! thank you very much!

Comment: Without using a symbolic calculation software like ***Mathematica***, this integral is hard to evaluate.  I could do it in the special case of $l = n - 1$ (for which $L_0^k = 1$).  I guess that you try to find the uncertainty in radial momentum: $\Delta p_r^2$, is that it?

Comment: [These integral formulas](https://functions.wolfram.com/Polynomials/LaguerreL3/21/ShowAll.html) should be helpful.

Comment: *$n^3*a^2*(l+\frac{1}{2})$* BTW, asterisks to indicate multiplication are an ugly programming thing. Math formulas don’t use them. I hope you don’t see them in your physics textbooks.